# Find text of length 4 from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to search all the words or text of length 4 available on my page and replace it by other text which is returned by a function using regex

```
$("#changeRandom").click(function() {
      $("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/([a-zA-Z]){4}/g,"hello"));
      });

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: You must post up your attempted code.

Comment: I guess I figured out what you were looking for. Check the posted answer.

Comment: You don't require a loop here. Check the updated answer.

Comment: but i want to use for all the elements available in body, not for a paragraph

Comment: i mean single paragraph. there will be multiple tags

Comment: This will do a global replacement in your entire document body, not just a P

Comment: how to use a variable value or function value in replace function in place of "exchange"

Comment: @chitrank Use `\b[\w]{4}\b` instead.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to loop here or jQuery, it can be simply accomplished with Js. But as your preference for jQuery is evident from your code, you can get this shit done in 3 simple steps:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network. Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network.Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network.</p>

<button onclick="replaceFunction()">Replace overflow with exchange</button>

<script>
function replaceFunction() {
  
    var repWith ="exchange";
    var content = $("body").html(); 
    var result = content.replace(/overflow/gi, repWith);
    $("body").html(result);
 
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is noot what i was looking for.